# Wordpress enqueue stylesheet only if a pattern is used

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, wordpress-gutenberg

Using Wordpress 6.3 Block Editor (Gutenberg) we can register block patterns. These patterns are a preconfigured collection of blocks.

```
add_action('init', function () {

    register_block_pattern(
        'my_test_pattern',
        array(
            'title' => 'My Test Pattern',
            "categories" => ['text'],
            'description' => 'Test',
            'content' => "<!-- wp:paragraph -->
            <p>Something</p>
            <!-- /wp:paragraph -->",
        )
    );

});
```

We can check that this pattern is registered across the entire site:

```
WP_Block_Patterns_Registry::get_instance()->is_registered("my_test_pattern")
```

But is there a way to check when it is actually used so that we can enqueue a stylesheet on pages **only** when it is used.

With blocks, there is a function called `has_block("block-name")` but there is no similar function for has_pattern.

EDIT / IDEA

I think the problem may be whilst blocks are saved with their names in post_content, patters are not with their containing blocks stored in post_content.

On idea would be to create a custom block. Provide a field in the InspectorControl to give a custom pattern name and when that block renders it it ensues a css file with that provided pattern name if it has not already be enqueued. I'm sure that will work but it seems a little over the top.

Answer (score 0):

Given a block pattern is a collection of blocks, and individual blocks have their own associated styles, maybe what you are looking for can be accomplished with [Block Themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes/) instead. This way, you could declare your required block pattern in the HTML template file as part of the theme and have finer control over the CSS styles via [theme.json](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/theme-json/#theme-json-elements) when the blocks appear together.

Another option is when you add a block pattern to a post/page, convert it into a [synced pattern](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/reusable-blocks) (*formerly known as a reusable block*). Now the synced pattern has a unique ID is associated with it that could be used to find out if it's in a post/page or include a custom CSS style to target it.

Comment: Both methods would load the styles regardless of whether the block was used. The idea is to only enqueue the stylesheet associated with the pattern when said pattern is used. I've found an alternative method creating template-specific stylesheets and with a custom block that loads assets when relevant. The only pitfall to both of these is that it requires the editor to be refreshed to see the styles added.